# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dftd3'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this File Not found error even though the file is in the corresponding directory. Can someone have a look please?

The detailed info of the error is as below:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/lbfgs.py", line 65, in __init__
 Optimizer.__init__(self, atoms, restart, logfile, trajectory,master,
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 234, in __init__
self.set_force_consistent()
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 325, in set_force_consistent
self.atoms.get_potential_energy(force_consistent=True)
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/atoms.py", line 728, in get_potential_energy
energy = self._calc.get_potential_energy(
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 709, in get_potential_energy
energy = self.get_property('energy', atoms)
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/dftd3.py", line 387, in get_property
dftd3_result = FileIOCalculator.get_property(self, name, atoms,
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 737, in get_property
self.calculate(atoms, [name], system_changes)
 File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/dftd3.py", line 220, in calculate
errorcode = subprocess.call(command,
 File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
 File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
 File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dftd3'
```

[Error Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC3y0.png)

And here is the file in the directory:

[File in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQNXw.png)

I tried to import a function from a .py file.

Comment: Howdy, 

I would recommend including the error codes into the question as most people would not to click into the links to see the errors.

cheers